# How do you mock a function that is part of that class under test gmock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am using googletest / googlemock (GTest/GMock).
I am only able to test the code below when `Selection` naturally returns false.
How would I simulate the example problem below?

I am having difficulty changing the return value of selection because it uses real code.

```
class frame
{
    bool Selection();
    void Actions();
};

void frame::Action()
{
    if (Selection())
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
}

void WrapAction()
{
    Frame->Action();
}

TEST_F(UITest, ActionWithSelectionTrue)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*Frame, Selection()).WillOnce(Return(true));

    WrapAction();
}

TEST_F(UITest, ActionWithSelectionFalse)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*Frame, Selection()).WillOnce(Return(false));
    WrapAction();
}
```

Comment: You should test behaviour, not lines of code. Don't try to break the integrity of the class. It has it's job to perform - let it do it's job in tests as well. Use your class in tests just as any other user should use it. Think under what condition can `Selection()` return `true`/`false`? How can you put your class in that state using only public functions?

Comment: Since class under test `frame` doesn't have dependencies there is nothing to mock, so `EXPECT_CALL` has no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional unit tests have the **A<sup>3</sup>** form:

1. **Assemble** (also called "Arrange"; setup your object under test)
2. **Act** (perform the desired action on the object)
3. **Assert** (validate the the proper values changed, events were emitted, etc.)

This is a valid form for tests and does not require a mock framework at all.

In a test with mocks, you may (depending on how your mock library works) have to amend this procedure to be **A<sup>4</sup>**:

1. **Assemble** (including injecting mocked dependencies)
2. **Anticipate** (set expectations on mocked dependencies by identifying expected calls, set return values, side effects, etc.)
3. **Act**
4. **Assert** (may have nothing else to assert if the mock expectations cover everything).

In your case, it is not clear what you are mocking. Where are the [dependencies you are injecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) that you are replacing with mocks?

Given the code you've shown us, I think you should use the **A<sup>3</sup>** test pattern. That would mean in the "Assemble" section, you configure the object by setting the selection, then you perform your action on it and check the result.

If you cannot work in the **A<sup>3</sup>** pattern, this probably means you need to refactor to better separate your dependencies. When you do that, you can then mock and test with the **A<sup>4</sup>** pattern.

Comment: the interal functionality of selection depends on a serial connection, it returns true or false depending if the device is connected or not. i will try to refactor the code so that not everything is in the single class. it is just really difficult to do because the code initially was written without any unit tests. if i change one thing it breaks everything else.

Comment: This is a perfect case for dependency injection -- you have a dependency on a serial port. To refactor, you would inject an object that mocks the serial port behavior (or perhaps higher-level functionality such as checking if data is ready and getting it regardless of the conduit of that data), then in the test you can control what the object under test experiences by manipulating the mocked serial port and then validate the object's responses. In this case, you want the **A4** test pattern.